# Append Character to specific Part of name using Rename Command

Tags: linux, rename, file-search

I am stock on a question using the rename command. I am having a list of files which are named as followed :

FT_440210.jpg
FT_4302110.jpg

I need to append "AGF" between FT_ and 440210. Resulting in : FT_AGF_440210.jpg.

After using a lot of options it can't seem to work. I have tried the -A parameter of the command which just append at the begging or end of a file or some wildcard things like :

rename -nv s/^_4302110/AGF *.jpg

Please can someone already had the problem, or at least an other option without rename command if needed.

Thank you,

Comment: [What exact `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/108618) are we talking about?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes we do. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `rename` command provided by the `rename` Debian package (a Perl version). Just something like this :

`prename s/FT/FT_AGF/ FT*.jpg`

With the `util-linux` version, you should type :

`rename.ul FT FT_AGF FT*jpg`

Comment: It's working thank you !